# Function with multiple classes that have a mixin

Tags: swift, generics, mixins

### The Mixin

I have a mixin that prints the assigns the class name as a `String` to an instance variable.

```
import Foundation

protocol Recyclable {
    static var name: String { get }
}

extension Recyclable {
    static var name: String {
        return String(describing: Self.self)
    }
}
```

There are two classes that implement the mixin:

```
class One: NSObject, Recyclable { }
class Two: NSObject, Recyclable { }
```

So if I want to print the class name, I can just

```
One.self.name // "One"
```

This works perfectly. Now let's get deeper.

### Generic function to print multiple given classes

Putting this into a function to print the name of all given classes. It needs to be a generic, since it can accept any class that conforms to the Recyclable `protocol`.

```
func printAllNames<T: NSObject>(_ things: T.Type...) where T: Recyclable {
    for thing in things {
        print(thing.name)
    }
}
```

If I use this for one class only, it works as expected.

```
printAllNames(One.self) // "One"
```

But when used with more than one, it errors out

```
printAllNames(One.self, Two.self)
```

> Playground execution failed: error: GenericMixins.playground:20:1:
>   error: generic parameter 'T' could not be inferred
>   printAllNames(One.self, Two.self)

---

Any hints on what might be happening?

Playground: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/q0b5b3oo0luj471/AABSG2QEOIj_SBsvtv7cEv-Ka?dl=0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up figuring it out. The right approach is to make function accept anything, and then check if what was accepted conforms to the protocol.

The function should be

```
func printAllNames(_ things: AnyObject...) {
    for thing in things {
        if let klass = thing.self as? Recyclable.Type {
            print(klass.name)
        }
    }
}
```

And then it works as expected

```
printAllNames(One.self, Two.self)
```

> One
>
> Two

---

Updated playground: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/9sjboo3lfu83662/AAC9CKn_dU_wrihCvKUfujQ7a?dl=0

Answer (score 1):

The problem, as [@dirtydanee says](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44430794/2976878), is that the generic placeholder `T` represents a *single* type to be satisfied at the call-site of the function. Therefore the variadic parameter `T.Type...` expresses a series of metatypes for the *same* type `T`.

The solution is simply to have a `Recyclable.Type...` parameter, which expresses a series of metatypes for *any* type that conforms to `Recyclable`:

```
func printAllNames(_ things: Recyclable.Type...) {
    for thing in things {
        print(thing.name)
    }
}

printAllNames(One.self, Two.self)
```

This doesn't express the `NSObject` constraint on `T` that you had, but you weren't using that constraint in the implementation of the function itself.

---

If this is just a simplified example, and you *actually* want to express a series of metatypes for any type that both inherits from `NSObject` and conforms to `Recyclable` – you cannot currently express this in Swift 3.

However in Swift 4, we *can* express this with [a class existential](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0156-subclass-existentials.md) of `NSObject & Recyclable`:

```
func printAllNames(_ things: (NSObject & Recyclable).Type...) {
    for thing in things {
        print(thing.name)
    }
}
```

Comment: Very good to know I can do this much better on Swift 4. I'm developing a module called Recycle github.com/mateusnroll/recycle. I'll make sure I update it to the new syntax when I migrate to the new swift :)

Comment: @MateusPinheiro From quickly looking at your repo, I don't see why you need to express that the metatypes need to describe types that also inherit from `NSObject`. A method parameter of type `Recyclable.Type...` should be all you need (and is available in Swift 3).